# Error 409 occurred in telebot when using multiprocessing [exe file]

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, telebot

I want to start another process, it will start, if I write to telegram bot "start". But right after this occurring the ERROR:

```
2022-04-11 11:16:13,602 (__init__.py:688 Thread-1) 
ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 409. 
Description: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request;
make sure that only one bot instance is running"
```

I am running ONLY one bot at the same time, already checked it. I found, that the error occurs when program trying to start a new process. Could anyone help me, please?

```
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import telebot
from telebot import types
from threading import Thread
import multiprocessing


def collecting(a):
    while True:
        print(a)
        sleep(3)

if __name__=='__main__':

    bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

    workers = []

    def listen():
        @bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
        def get_text(message):
            id = message.chat.id
            mes = message.text
            if mes=='start':
                bot.send_message(id, 'okey')
                workers.append([str(datetime.now())])
            else:
                bot.send_message(id, mes)
        bot.polling()

    Thread(target=listen).start()
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        x = workers[:]
        for i in range(len(x)):
            multiprocessing.Process(target=collecting, args=(x[i],)).start()
            del workers[i]
```

UPD: Forgot to say, this error occurred only when I create exe file and run this code like exe program. This is how I create exe file:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import=pkg_resources.py2_warn --onefile Program.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I forgot to add this:

```
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
```

And then after `if__name__=="__main__":`  also need to write `freeze_support()`.